# Something similar to this C# code in Ruby on Rails

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, translation

I am trying to get a collection of objects based on a conditions. Now normally in C# I would do something like this

```
employeesCollection.Where(emp => emp.Name == "john");
```

how can I do something similar in Ruby on Rails (I am trying to map a collection of objects to a select but I only want to map certain objects that match a condition.

My current ruby on rails code looks like this

```
<%= select( 'page', 'id', @post.pages.map {|page| [page.title, page.id]}) %>
```

I want to add a condition to an attribute of page

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just throw a [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125) block in there before `map`:

```
>> [1,2,3,4,5].select { |x| x.odd? }.map{ |x| x*x }
=> [1, 9, 25]
```

A synonym for select is [`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003124).

As you probably guessed, `select` in Ruby is approximately equivalent to LINQ's `Where`.  Select takes a block, and each element in your `Enumerable` is passed to that block; when the block returns true (non-false, non-nil), then that element is `select`ed.

The antonym for `select` is [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003126).  `reject` is preferred when your select is negative: that is to say,

```
ary.select {|x| x != 'foo'}
```

is less preferable than

```
ary.reject {|x| x == 'foo'}
```

Comment: You're a god among men, great answer. Thanks!